# Regularization of divergent integral with Resiue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, residue-calculus

I am currently trying to calculate the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} d k \frac{k}{k^{2}-(a+i \varepsilon)^2}
$$
where $a$ and $\varepsilon$ are real parameters. For this, I have found the residue theorem in the form
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} R(z) d z=-\sum_{k} \operatorname{Res}\left(R(z) \log (z), z_{k}\right)
$$
This would give me the result (I use $z_1 = a+i \varepsilon$ and $z_1 = -a-i \varepsilon$)
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \left( \text{Log} [a+i \varepsilon] + \text{Log} [-a-i \varepsilon] \right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} d k \frac{k}{k^{2}-(a+i \varepsilon)^2}
$$
which is probably not right? See e.g. [https://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~herfort/BAKK/Roetzer.pdf] on page 8. I guess the problem lies in the fact that $$\text{Grad} (k^2 - (a + i \varepsilon)^2)  - \text{Grad} (k) \ngtr 1 $$
Is this correct? And if this is the case, do I have to use an upper cutoff for the integral to be bounded?

Comment: which contour are u using for the residue theorem? Guess there is the first problem

Comment: I found the theorem on page 8 in [https://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~herfort/BAKK/Roetzer.pdf]. I guess they used a keyhole contour.

Comment: the problem is, that with a keyhole you can't neglect the contributions from the part of the arc, since the integrand doesn't vanish fast enough (i think this can be fixed, but you have to be careful ). 
Underlying to that, your base integral has a singurality at $k=\infty$ which doesn't seem to be accounted for (the epsilon only takes care of the singularities at $k=a$).

Comment: You will need (as you said) some momentum cutoff to make sense of it